# error calling c# com interop dll

Tags: c#

I have a python project that calls a c++ dll that calls a c# dll.
I wanted all to run without installing visual studio 2008.

I allready made the c++ part by installing Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86) and I also installed .net framework 3.5.

But now, when I call a function from c++ dll (and this one calls its correspondent in c#), it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Public\SoundLog\Code\Código Python\SoundLog\SoundLog.py", line 821, in OnStart
    Auxiliar.DataCollection.start(self)
  File "C:\Users\Public\SoundLog\Code\Código Python\SoundLog\Auxiliar\DataCollection.py", line 68, in start
    SoundLogDLL.run()
  File "C:\Users\Public\SoundLog\Code\Código Python\SoundLog\Auxiliar\SoundLogDLL.py", line 61, in run
    return apiRun()
WindowsError: exception code 0xe0434f4d
```

This works where I've installed full VS2008 pro version.

What am I missing and what can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to figure out what the real error is and since it's on a machine without VS you can't attach the debugger as usual, but you should be able to manually attach a remote debugger without installing anything.

See here for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx

If for any reason you can't do that, you might have to set it up to do a dump when the application crashes. Here's some information about how to do that:

http://blogs.technet.com/askperf/archive/2008/02/05/ws2008-windows-error-reporting.aspx

You can then copy the dump to a machine with visual studio and hopefully find the problem.